# Use gsub in R to remove some rows based on some pattern

Tags: r, regex, data.table, gsub

I have a data table which some text columns. I want to delete those rows which have MN followed by some number. For instance
MN 894080/901060/905034,MN 90706 etc.

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(
variable= c(
"MN 894080/901060/905034 - a file has some text.",
"L2 BLOCK AMER] [VVol MN 941737][DU MN 934010] a file has some text",
"MN 907068 || bdheks;",
"MN#287627/901060/905034 a file has some text ",
"MN# 944179 || a file has some text",
"(MN #927427)a file has some text",
"MN 933281 - a file has some text",
"a file has some text",
" a file has some text Mnuq"))
```

Final output should look like below:

```
dt
  variable
a file has some text
a file has some text Mnuq
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `grepl` solution

```
dt[!grepl("MN.*\\d", dt$variable)]
#                      variable
# 1:       a file has some text
# 2:  a file has some text Mnuq
```

Comment: The dt within the scope of `[` is not necessary to get to variable